# Papertrail and Carrierwave

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, carrierwave, paper-trail-gem

I  have a model that use both: Carrierwave for store photos, and `PaperTrail` for versioning.

I also configured Carrierwave for store diferent files when updates (That's because I want to version the photos) with `config.remove_previously_stored_files_after_update = false`

The problem is that `PaperTrail` try to store the whole Ruby Object from the photo (CarrierWave Uploader) instead of simply a string (that would be its url)

(version table, column object)

```
---
first_name: Foo
last_name: Bar
photo: !ruby/object:PhotoUploader
  model: !ruby/object:Bla
    attributes:
      id: 2
      first_name: Foo1
      segundo_nombre: 'Bar1'
      ........
```

How can I fix this to store a simple string in the photo version?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can override `item_before_change` on your versioned model so you don't call the uploader accesor directly and use `write_attribute` instead. Alternatively, since you might want to do that for several models, you can monkey-patch the method directly, like this:

```
module PaperTrail
  module Model
    module InstanceMethods
      private
        def item_before_change
          previous = self.dup
          # `dup` clears timestamps so we add them back.
          all_timestamp_attributes.each do |column|
            previous[column] = send(column) if respond_to?(column) && !send(column).nil?
          end
          previous.tap do |prev|
            prev.id = id
            changed_attributes.each do |attr, before|
              if defined?(CarrierWave::Uploader::Base) && before.is_a?(CarrierWave::Uploader::Base)
                prev.send(:write_attribute, attr, before.url && File.basename(before.url))
              else
                prev[attr] = before
              end
            end
          end
        end
    end
  end
end
```

Not sure if it's the best solution, but it seems to work.

Comment: I tried putting this code in /config/initializers/papertrail.rb, but it's still adding the full upload object. This is with Rails 4.1.

Comment: As an alternative, I found it's easiest to just mount on a different attribute, which avoids the issue all together with paper trail, no monkey patching needed

Comment: This doesn't work in versions of PaperTrail released since January 2015 or so when `item_before_change` was renamed. Since then, it's been renamed and changed in various ways.

Answer (score 6):

Adding @beardedd's comment as an answer because I think this is a better way to handle the problem.

Name your database columns something like `picture_filename` and then in your model mount the uploader using:

`class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_paper_trail
  mount_uploader :picture, PictureUploader, mount_on: :picture_filename
end`

You still use the `user.picture.url` attribute to access your model but PaperTrail will store revisions under `picture_filename`.

Comment: Is this really a good way? Will there only change the file name when replacing an uploaded file, or will there also be a lot of meta information like image width, height, etc.? This would be lost when only tracking filename, and when restoring an old version the infos would be incorrect.

Comment: I made a quick test: I compared the dumps of two full carrierwave objects (one with an uploaded file `avatar.jpg` and one with `nayeli.jpg`). It seems that really only the timestamps and file names are different, except one line (#237) where the file's name of the previously uploaded file is stored (`url.jpg`, which was the file before `avatar.jpg`). As far as I can see, your solution should basically work, while line 237 would be wrong when restoring revisions as it isn't tracked correctly. See results here: https://github.com/jmuheim/base/commit/c5f93b261efa02ff70265ef7397dfd77aecb644e

Answer (score 2):

Here is a bit updated version of monkeypatch from @rabusmar, I use it for rails 4.2.0 and paper_trail 4.0.0.beta2, in `/config/initializers/paper_trail.rb`.

The second method override is required if you use optional `object_changes` column for versions. It works in a bit strange way for carrierwave + fog if you override `filename` in uploader, old value will be from cloud and new one from local filename, but in my case it's ok.

Also I have not checked if it works correctly when you restore old version.

```
module PaperTrail
  module Model
    module InstanceMethods
      private

      # override to keep only basename for carrierwave attributes in object hash
      def item_before_change
        previous = self.dup
        # `dup` clears timestamps so we add them back.
        all_timestamp_attributes.each do |column|
          if self.class.column_names.include?(column.to_s) and not send("#{column}_was").nil?
            previous[column] = send("#{column}_was")
          end
        end
        enums = previous.respond_to?(:defined_enums) ? previous.defined_enums : {}
        previous.tap do |prev|
          prev.id = id # `dup` clears the `id` so we add that back
          changed_attributes.select { |k,v| self.class.column_names.include?(k) }.each do |attr, before|
            if defined?(CarrierWave::Uploader::Base) && before.is_a?(CarrierWave::Uploader::Base)
              prev.send(:write_attribute, attr, before.url && File.basename(before.url))
            else
              before = enums[attr][before] if enums[attr]
              prev[attr] = before
            end
          end
        end
      end

      # override to keep only basename for carrierwave attributes in object_changes hash
      def changes_for_paper_trail
        _changes = changes.delete_if { |k,v| !notably_changed.include?(k) }
        if PaperTrail.serialized_attributes?
          self.class.serialize_attribute_changes(_changes)
        end
        if defined?(CarrierWave::Uploader::Base)
          Hash[
              _changes.to_hash.map do |k, values|
                [k, values.map { |value| value.is_a?(CarrierWave::Uploader::Base) ? value.url && File.basename(value.url) : value }]
              end
          ]
        else
          _changes.to_hash
        end
      end

    end
  end
end
```

Comment: This doesn't prevent a previous file to be overwritten with a new file of the same name.

Comment: Restoring an old version DOESN'T work on `model.reload`! If you do a `user.previous_version.save`, `user` will still point to the latest file, and `user.reload` also won't fix this. You have to do a manual `user = User.find(user.id)`, then it will point to the previous file. Is there a fix for this? Typically between requests this isn't a problem, but it's still a bug.

Comment: This doesn't work in versions of PaperTrail released since January 2015 or so when `item_before_change` and `changes_for_paper_trail` were renamed.

Answer (score 1):

This is what actually functions for me, put this on config/initializers/paper_trail/.rb

```
module PaperTrail
  module Reifier
    class << self
      def reify_attributes(model, version, attrs)
        enums = model.class.respond_to?(:defined_enums) ? model.class.defined_enums : {}
        AttributeSerializers::ObjectAttribute.new(model.class).deserialize(attrs)
        attrs.each do |k, v|

          is_enum_without_type_caster = ::ActiveRecord::VERSION::MAJOR < 5 && enums.key?(k)

          if model.send("#{k}").is_a?(CarrierWave::Uploader::Base)
            if v.present?
               model.send("remote_#{k}_url=", v["#{k}"][:url])
               model.send("#{k}").recreate_versions!
            else
               model.send("remove_#{k}!")
            end
          else
              if model.has_attribute?(k) && !is_enum_without_type_caster
                model[k.to_sym] = v
              elsif model.respond_to?("#{k}=")
                model.send("#{k}=", v)
              elsif version.logger
                version.logger.warn(
                  "Attribute #{k} does not exist on #{version.item_type} (Version id: #{version.id})."
                )
              end
            end
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

This overrides the reify method to work on S3 + heroku

For uploaders to keep old files from updated or deleted records do this in the uploader

```
configure do |config|
   config.remove_previously_stored_files_after_update = false
end
def remove!
   true
end
```

Then make up some routine to clear old files from time to time, good luck

Comment: `model.send("#{k}").recreate_versions!` does not seem to reinstate the file object for me :(

Comment: Actually, I think it is working. I just needed to call save on the model where I was testing this out. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I want to add to the previous answers the following:

It can happen that you upload different files with the same name, and this may overwrite your previous file, so you won't be able to restore the old one.

You may [use a timestamp in file names](https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave/wiki/How-to:-Use-a-timestamp-in-file-names) or [create random and unique filenames for all versioned files](https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave/wiki/How-to%3A-Create-random-and-unique-filenames-for-all-versioned-files).

**Update**

This doesn't seem to work in all edge cases for me, when assigning more than a single file to the same object within a single request request.

I'm using this right now:

```
def filename
  [@cache_id, original_filename].join('-') if original_filename.present?
end
```

This seems to work, as the `@cache_id` is generated for each and every upload again (which isn't the case as it seems for the ideas provided in the links above).

Answer (score 0):

**@Sjors Provoost**

We also need to override **pt_recordable_object** method in **PaperTrail::Model::InstanceMethods** module

```
  def pt_recordable_object
    attr = attributes_before_change
    object_attrs = object_attrs_for_paper_trail(attr)

    hash = Hash[
        object_attrs.to_hash.map do |k, value|
          [k, value.is_a?(CarrierWave::Uploader::Base) ? value.url && File.basename(value.url) : value ]
        end
    ]

    if self.class.paper_trail_version_class.object_col_is_json?
      hash
    else
      PaperTrail.serializer.dump(hash)
    end
  end
```